# Correlation of All Variables with Target Variable in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, correlation

I have a table with 270 columns. I chose one of these as a target variable and I want to write a query finds correlations for each variable separately with target column. Is there a way to do this without hardcoding the names of the columns in corr function? I'm using Oracle SQL.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  But in Oracle 12+, you might find this a little simpler:

```
select x.which, corr(x.target, x.source)
from t cross join lateral
     (select 'source001' as which, target, source1 as source from dual union all
      select 'source002' as which, target, source2 as source from dual union all
      . . .
      select 'source270' as which, target, source270 as source from dual
     ) x
group by which;
```

For *just* correlation, this is no simpler than listing out the `corr()` functions individually.  But you can easily add more statistics -- say, `min()`, `max()`, or `count()` -- without repeating all the columns (or running into column limits).